# Find first div after THIS keyword

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="sort3" class="droptrue connectedSortable  ui-sortable" data-update-url="http://localhost:5000/workorders/sort " data-wostatus-id="236">
   <li class="workorder" id="workorder_37" style="">
      <div class=" 3" data-maxsynch="E">
```

The following picks up the data wostatus_id:

```
$(this).data('wostatus-id')
```

But, I haven't figured out how to get the data maxsynch.  I tried this:

```
$(this).find("div:first").data('maxsynch')
```

It gets a maxsynch value, but not from the first div.

Comment: what is `this` in context ? Is it `li`, `ul` or something else?

Comment: `$(this).children("div").eq(0).data('maxsynch')`, if `this` is the `li` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of the following:

```
1) $(this).find('div[data-maxsynch]').first().data('data-maxsynch');

2) $(this).find('div[data-maxsynch]').first().attr('data-maxsynch');
```

This locates the first nested div that contains the ***data-maxsynch*** data attribute and pulls its value.

Comment: @moonwave99 Thanks for the edit. Fixing that now. Much appreciated!

Comment: @PalashMondal Have you refreshed the answer? I updated that a couple minutes ago? Let me know if it didn't take and I'll try to update it again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `:first-of-type` instead of `:first`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).find("div[data-maxsynch]").data('maxsynch')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qUEpW/)